# Using variables in thymeleaf html

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have a thymeleaf html:

```
<div class="xxx">
        <label for="data.name1" th:text="#{name1}" th:for="data.name1">name1</label>
</div>
```

and want to make a condition: if ${data.type} is equal to "TYPE_A" then use name1 but if not then instead of name1 use name2. This is my try:

```
<div th:with="myVariable= ${data.type} == 'TYPE_A' ? 'name1' : 'name2'">
      <div class="xxx">
        <label for="data." + $myVariable th:text="#{$myVariable}" th:for="data." + $myVariable>$myVariable</label>
      </div>
</div>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? I note that (as the highlighting shows) the `label` tag in your second block is malformed (dangling `+ $myVariable`s), and you probably only meant to use `${myVariable}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This...

```
<div th:with="myVariable= ${data.type eq 'TYPE_A' ? 'name1' : 'name2'}">
  <div class="xxx">
    <label th:text="#{${myVariable}}" th:for="${'data.'+myVariable}">name1</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: what about first `for`? is it unecessary? one `th:for` is enough?

Comment: Yes it is unecessary... but you can include it if you want natural templating. Check this link https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/petclinic.html

Comment: yes I need it I think... can ya suggest how add this? Cuz: `<label for="${'data.'+myVariable}" th:text="#{${myVariable}}" th:for="${'data.'+myVariable}">name1</label>` gives error on `for="${'data.'+myVariable}"` saying "invalid id reference"...

Comment: Do you have any entry in messages.properties for name1 and name2?
If not then use it like this...

<label for="data.name1" th:text="${myVariable}" th:for="${'data.'+myVariable}">name1</label>

Comment: You don't need to use variable syntax in simple for attribute... And # is used to access messages from messages.properties